# Why isn't PostgreSQL using an index in a Merge Join scenario?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

```
explain select count(1) from tab1_201502 t1, tab2_201502 t2
            where t1.serv_no=t2.serv_no
                and t1.PC_LOGIN_COUNT1 >5
                    and t1.FET_WZ_FEE < 80
                        and t2.ALL_FLOW_2G<50;

                                QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=4358706.25..4358706.26 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Merge Join  (cost=4339930.99..4358703.30 rows=1179 width=0)
         Merge Cond: ((t1.serv_no)::text = (t2.serv_no)::text)
         ->  Index Scan using tab1_201502_serv_no_idx on tab1_201502 t1
              (cost=0.56..6239071.57 rows=263219 width=12)
               Filter: ((pc_login_count1 > 5::numeric)
                        AND (fet_wz_fee < 80::numeric))
         ->  Sort  (cost=4339914.76..4340306.63 rows=156747 width=12)
               Sort Key: t2.serv_no
               ->  Seq Scan on tab2_201502 t2
                    (cost=0.00..4326389.00 rows=156747 width=12)
                     Filter: (all_flow_2g < 50::numeric)
```

All tables are indexed on `serv_no`.

Why is PostgreSQL ignoring the `tab2_201502` index for scan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select count(1)
from tab1_201502 t1 join
     tab2_201502 t2 
     on t1.serv_no = t2.serv_no 
where t1.PC_LOGIN_COUNT1 > 5 and t1.FET_WZ_FEE < 80 and t2.ALL_FLOW_2G < 50;
```

Postgres is deciding that filtering by the `where` clause is more important than performing the `join`.

I would recommend trying two sets of indexes for this query.  They are:  `tab2_201502(ALL_FLOW_2G, serv_no)` and `tab1_201502(serv_no, PC_LOGIN_COUNT1, FET_WZ_FEE)`.

The second pair is:  `tab1_201502(PC_LOGIN_COUNT1, FET_WZ_FEE, serv_no)` and `tab2_201502(serv_no, ALL_FLOW_2G)`.

Which works better depends on which table is the driving table for the `join`.

Comment: I don't understand why tab1 can do filter with index scan but tab2 not? I think first choice is better.

Comment: @user2114551 . . . The plan that Postgres chooses depends on the statistics maintained on the tables.  It has an optimizer to figure these things out.

Comment: ,I tried "set enable_seqscan=off", and perfomence was much better.